# flashScrollIndicators to textView that was added programmatically to subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have added a textView to the view programatically like this

```
@implementation viewController {
    UITextView *textView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame];
        textView.text = [self.text objectForKey:[arrayKeys objectAtIndex:i]];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:textView];
    }
}
```

I put it like this so I can have 4 pages in a scroll view for each textView. But how can I, when the user opens the view controller, flashScrollIndicators?

Comment: Did you try `[textView flashScrollIndicators];` ?

Comment: @Visput did, that's what I'm asking, that doesn't work (I tried it in `viewDidAppear` and `scrollViewDidScroll`). I think it is because I used the same textView four times for the scrollView.

Comment: Does textView contains enough text to scroll? In other case flash indicators won't be shown if content size is less then size of frame.

Comment: Yep, it has lots of text to scroll.

Comment: Maybe it's because you use the same frame for all text fields `textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame];` and `flashScrollIndicators` is called for bottom text field that isn't visible?